# Probability of a Specific Result

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to validate a small Monte Carlo that I am running:

A small bucket contains seven ping pong balls numbered $1$ through $7$.  A ball is drawn at random from the bucket, the number recorded, and the ball returned to the bucket. The experiment is to repeat this sampling process $420$ times.

At the end of a single experiment, I would expect that each of the seven counters would be about $60$.  This is because for any draw you are equally likely to pick any number.   I repeated the experiment on the computer $5000$ times.  I did not get a single result of $(60,60,60,60,60,60,60)$

I was a little surprised.  What is the probability of getting exactly $60$ for all seven counters??

Comment: I can assure you it's way way WAY smaller than $1/5000$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer for one attempt is $\dfrac{\displaystyle {420 \choose 60}{360 \choose 60}{300 \choose 60}{240 \choose 60}{180 \choose 60}{120 \choose 60}{60 \choose 60}}{7^{420}} = \dfrac{\displaystyle {420 !}}{(60!)^7 7^{420}}$.

This is about $5 \times 10^{-8}$, so your number of experiments is a little too small to make it likely you would observe it.

Comment: Thank you Henry..............does this mean that any *specific* outcome is equally likely.....is (420,0,0,0,0,0,0) just as likely as (60,60,60,60,60,60,60) ??

Comment: No $(420,0,0,0,0,0,0) $ has a probability of $1/7^{420} \approx 10^{-355}$ or seven times this if you do not mind which value appears consistently